# Remotely include directories with PHP

Tags: php, include, backend

I've done some research on an issue I'm having with taking a remote directory from `Server A` and linking that directory to `Server B`. I'm not fully sure if I can take the remote directory using PHP and use the contents from that directory on `Server B`

Here's what is what I want to go one between both servers

Server A (code.php)

```
<?php

  $FileTitle = '/code/';

  if (!isset($_GET['file'])) {
    exit('This file cannot be found');
  }

  $FileTitle = $_GET['file'];

?>
```

What I have going on with this script is that every time a person enters in a url ending with /code.php?=testfile.txt or any other file in the directory /code/ on `Server A` will be echoed using `<?php echo $FileTitle; ?>`. My problem with this is that I host all the files on `Server A` rather on `Server B`. I want the title of the file from the URL to show up in index.php on `Server B`

Server B (index.php)

```
<?php
include 'http://example.com/code.php';
?>

<?php echo $FileTitle; ?>
```

I'm planning for this to take the code from `Server A` and be able to find the directory /code/ on that server as well.

I've done a ton a research the past few days both on Stackoverflow and around the internet. I haven't found anything even close to what I am trying to do. If you can, please show me how to do this. I would really appreciate figuring out how to have a remote connection to a file on another server and be able to use that file remotely. Thanks :)

Comment: how are server A and B connected?

Comment: I'm attempting to include Server A with PHP include.

Comment: that's not what i asked.

Comment: Do you mean are they from the same service?

Comment: `include 'http://example.com/code.php';` will not work as expected.  code.php will be parsed by example.com and the source will not be included.  That would only work if PHP was being output as plain text by example.com.  Does it make sense to use a proxy module?

Comment: @drew010 I already knew include couldn't do the job, but it was something I already had known how to do with basic file paths. Proxy module, not sure. All I need is one file from Server A.

Comment: Ok sorry, well I suppose the security risk could be slightly increased, but in the past I have included a file remotely by serving the PHP source as plain text so it wouldn't be parsed by the remote server and the source was executed on the server doing the include.  You can see a similar example here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php  That may be what you need.

Comment: I was thinking if you are using Apache, [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) could be a solution as well, maybe slightly overcomplicated depending on what you are trying to do, but it works well for running code from a private server transparently through a directory on an external domain.

Comment: @drew010 Np, I really appreciate your help. I just tried making including the the code.php file as a text file but still get the same result.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I forgot to mention, the php setting [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) must be enabled in php.ini.  In php 5.2+ there is an option `allow_url_include` as well.  `allow_url_fopen` has to be enabled for that too.

Comment: That I can't control unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

code.php will execute on the remote server so you will get the output of code.php if any.  The only thing I can think of is writing a script that outputs code.php..

Ex:
server b, index.php

```
<?php
eval(str_replace(array('<?php', '?>'), '', file_get_contents('http://example.com/sendcode.php)));
?>
```

server a, sendcode.php

```
<?php
$code = file_get_contents('code.php');
echo $code;
?>
```

Completely insecure, but it works.

Edited: try new server b code.  If that doesn't work I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I see what you mean, and that could work. Though I get this as an error result http://payload.site88.net/test.php?=Tech%20support.mp4 - This is on Server B

Comment: I think that worked, except that there's an unexpected charter input somewhere in Server B code...

Comment: +1 A more secure solution would be to get the php file from server A through FTP with your PHP script on server B.